# I want to always redirect to home page

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am testing an app, and at each changes I do in js, I would like that it load the home page.

Right now, if I am on a specific route, it will hot reload that route.

Is there a way to force homepage on refresh in angular ?

Comment: Code… show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach may be to add a route guard that checks for some global variable.

For example; first create a service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyRedirectCheckService {
  redirectToHomePage = true;
}
```

Create a route guard that uses the service, something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class checkFirstLoadGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot, 
    myRedirectCheckService: MyRedirectCheckService ): boolean {
    return myRedirectCheckService.redirectToHomePage;
  }
}
```

Then add the canActivate route guard to your router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
          { path: 'main', component: MainComponent },
          { path: 'child', component: ChildComponent, canActivate: [CheckFirstLoadGuard]},
          { path: '**', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ]
];
```

In your main component constructor, be sure to toggle the value:

```
constructor(myRedirectCheckService: MyRedirectCheckService) {
  myRedirectCheckService.redirectToHomePage = false;
}
```

This is just one approach, and code is not tested in the context of an actual app.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
window.location = ''
```

instead of

```
this.router.navigate([''])
```

to force refresh

if using inside  element, use href attribute instead of routerLink attribute